# How do I keep photos in tumblr text posts within the post boundaries?

Tags: html, css, tumblr

How do I make sure photos added to tumblr text posts do not go outside the background of the post?

I want to make sure that, wherever the photo is in the reblog chain, the photo will still sit inside the background.

The html for my text post is:

```
{block:Text}
        <div class="text">
            {block:Title}
                <h3>
                    <a href="{Permalink}">{Title}</a>
                </h3>
            {/block:Title}
            {Body}
            <ul class="like-reblog">
                <li>{LikeButton color="white"}</li>
                <li>{ReblogButton color="white"}</li>
                <li>{block:NoteCount}<a href="{Permalink}#notes">{NoteCountWithLabel}</a>{/block:NoteCount}</li>
                <li>{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{Month} {DayOfMonth}</a>{/block:Date}</li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="tags">
                <li>{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}
            </ul>

        </div>
        {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}
        {/block:Text}
```

The css for my text posts is:

```
.text {
        background: rgba(251, 230, 202, 1);
        margin: 40px auto;
        padding: 20px;
        width: 500px;
        border: 2px solid #fff;
        background-position:center;
    }
    .text a {
        font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: rgb(52, 47, 20);
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .text img {
        max-width: 400px;
        height: auto;
}
    .text blockquote{
        border-left: 3px solid #fff;
        padding: 0px 10px;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.text img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;}
```

This should fix it. Images will shrink to fit within the reblog blockquotes.